# Magento 2: Load storeview id in controller returns error

Tags: magento2, store-view

I loaded following class into my controller:

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace;
```

And injected it in my constructor:

```
StoreManagerInterf‌​ace $storeManagerInterface,
```

However it returns following error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Qxs\Verkoopje\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor
```

How to load the storeManager in my controller?

Comment: Remove generated folder please.

Comment: Thanks, I thought i never have to do that in developer mode... Now it returns : Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace does not exist
Class Qxs\Verkoopje\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you

Comment: Try to run php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: It keeps returning:Class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterf‌​ace does not exist             
  Class Qxs\Verkoopje\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor generation error: Th  
  e requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' direct  
  ory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di  
  :compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to w  
  rite --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add t  
  he generated class object to the signature of the related construct method,  
   only.

Comment: Go  to this path vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManagerInterface.php and check please file available or not.

Comment: yes it is there

Comment: Upload your full controller code please.

Comment: changing class to use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager; solved the issue, many thx!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below way :

```
protected $_storeManager;    

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    .....
)
{
    .....
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    .....
}

/**
 * Get store identifier
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
}
```

After inject class in construct remove generated folder and clean cache.